# class properties to jquery datatables asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

After seeing a lot of code samples, I cant make a simple datatable using Jquery Datatables and MVC.

I got the error

My controller is this

```
 public class DataTableController : Controller
{
    // GET: DataTable
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var registros = new List<PruebaClass>();
        var pruebaClass1 = new PruebaClass
        {
            Race = "Aliens",
            Year = 1990,
            Total = 50

        };

        var pruebaClass2 = new PruebaClass
        {
            Race = "MArcianos",
            Year = 200,
            Total = 20

        };
        registros.Add(pruebaClass1);
        registros.Add(pruebaClass2);

        var resultado = Json(new { aaData = registros.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return resultado;
    }

    public class PruebaClass
    {
        public string Race { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }

}
```

My view is this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table id="miTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Race</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyDataTablejs.js"></script>

    }
```

And my javascript file is this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#miTable').DataTable(
        {

            "sAjaxSource": "../DataTable/GetData",

            "columns": [
                { "Data": "Race", "autoWidth": true },
                { "Data": "Year", "autoWidth": true },
                { "Data": "Total", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        });
});
```

I can reach the ActionResult, and my view shows two rows but the content of each cell is null. And I got the awfull error Datatables warning (table id= 'miTable')Requested unknown parameter '0' from the datasource '0' .

Im pretty sure that the problem is the source (maybe the JSON format) and the column name mapping, but I cant figure out what is. 
Any help?

Comment: Try using indexes instead of names: `"Data": 0`, `"Data": 1` etc.  You may still have problems because you're not returning any rowcount values for the datatable to use, but let's deal with the first error.

Comment: I was using the wrong properties for the column definition and the data definition. Shame on me :D

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. Finally I matched the columns definition with apropiate options in the jquery file. I knew that I was missing something. All I need to do was to use the "aocolumns" and "mDataProp"

this code solves all

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#miTable').DataTable(
        {

            "sAjaxSource": "../DataTable/GetData",

            "aoColumns": [

                { "mDataProp": "Race", "autoWidth": true },
                { "mDataProp": "Year", "autoWidth": true },
                { "mDataProp": "Total", "autoWidth": true }
            ]




        });
});
```